# nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream - Ignore/deactivate instead of quit?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

Currently I build different docker container with different docker-compose files. So fare, all containers can communicate with each other when, when I start the containers in the right order.

Now, I have a container which acts as proxy for the other containers. Problem is now, that when the other containers are not started, nginx quit after start with

```
proxy_1  | nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "backend" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:27
```

Thats the related part:

```
    location ~ ^/api/ {
        expires off;
        rewrite /api/(.*) /api/$1  break;
        proxy_pass http://backend:80;
    }
```

Is there any chance to stop nginx from rebooting and instead try again and again until the other service is available?

Comment: Found solution now to my question here: https://serverfault.com/a/935559